Gunicorn ошибка 'exit-code'
Решился впервые попробовать выгрузить свой пет проект на сервер, для хостинга использую DigitalOcean, но столкнулся с ошибкой  'exit-code'
Но думаю лучше все показать сначала для ясности. Проект находится по пути store-server/store/, а само виртуальное окружение на директорию ниже - store-server/
Зависимости:
(venv) gaijin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01:~/store-server$ pip list
Package              Version
-------------------- -----------
...
eventlet             0.36.1
flake8               7.0.0
flower               2.0.1
greenlet             3.0.3
gunicorn             22.0.0
...

Настройка gunicorn.socket

Настройка gunicorn.service

Следуя инструкции DigitalOcean: Документация, выполняю ряд команд

Вроде все хорошо но когда использую команду
sudo journalctl -u gunicorn.socket 
sudo systemctl status gunicorn

Но после чего получаю ошибки, в чем может быть проблема и как решить?)


Во-первых, все тексты должны быть текстами, а не скриншотами. Во-вторых, а вручную без systemd пробовали запускать?

Ошибка была видимо в том, что насколько я понимаю он принадлежал только root пользователю
(venv) gaijin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01:~/store-server/store$ ls -l /run/gunicorn.sock
srw-rw-rw- 1 root root 0 May 12 16:05 /run/gunicorn.sock
(venv) gaijin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01:~/store-server/store$

Потому я изменил владельца сокета на своего юзера - gaijin, И перезапустил gunicorn
(venv) gaijin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01:~/store-server/store$ sudo chown gaijin:gaijin /run/gunicorn.sock
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-05-12 16:05:46 UTC; 1h 25min ago
   Triggers: ● gunicorn.service
     Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

May 12 16:05:46 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.


(venv) gaijin@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01:~/store-server/store$ sudo systemctl status gunicorn.service
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-05-12 17:40:29 UTC; 1min 35s ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
   Main PID: 135946 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 498)
     Memory: 214.3M
        CPU: 5.057s
     CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.service
             ├─135946 /home/gaijin/store-server/venv/bin/python3 /home/gaijin/store-server/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock store.wsgi:application
             ├─135947 /home/gaijin/store-server/venv/bin/python3 /home/gaijin/store-server/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock store.wsgi:application
             ├─135948 /home/gaijin/store-server/venv/bin/python3 /home/gaijin/store-server/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock store.wsgi:application
             └─135949 /home/gaijin/store-server/venv/bin/python3 /home/gaijin/store-server/venv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock store.wsgi:application

May 12 17:40:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: Stopped gunicorn daemon.
May 12 17:40:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Consumed 6.218s CPU time.
May 12 17:40:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
May 12 17:40:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 gunicorn[135946]: [2024-05-12 17:40:29 +0000] [135946] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 22.0.0
May 12 17:40:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 gunicorn[135946]: [2024-05-12 17:40:29 +0000] [135946] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn.sock (135946)
May 12 17:40:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 gunicorn[135946]: [2024-05-12 17:40:29 +0000] [135946] [INFO] Using worker: sync
May 12 17:40:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 gunicorn[135947]: [2024-05-12 17:40:29 +0000] [135947] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 135947
May 12 17:40:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 gunicorn[135948]: [2024-05-12 17:40:29 +0000] [135948] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 135948
May 12 17:40:29 ubuntu-s-1vcpu-512mb-10gb-fra1-01 gunicorn[135949]: [2024-05-12 17:40:29 +0000] [135949] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 135949


В таком случае юнит gunicorn.socket вам вообще не нужен

@andreymal а почему?

А потому что файл сокета всё равно создаёт gunicorn самостоятельно, а этот ваш gunicorn.socket только мешает ему сделать это

Правда, каталог /run принадлежит пользователю root, из-за чего gunicorn не имеет прав на запись в него, так что независимо от наличия или отсутствия gunicorn.socket всё сломается после перезагрузки сервера. Переместите файл сокета в какой-нибудь каталог, в котором gunicorn имеет права на запись

А вообще для создания такого каталога systemd предоставляет опцию RuntimeDirectory или целую отдельную службу systemd-tmpfiles

@andreymal Но если дать гуникорну доступ к каталогу /run это может быть небезопасно верно?

Так не надо его давать, надо использовать другой каталог
